# How can I display a mysql bit(64) column as a string of ones and zeros?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, cast

We have a MySQL 5.5 database  with a table that holds a number of 64-bit values which are used for calculating the [hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance).  The columns for these are defined as `BIT(64)` and are populated using the bit-field literal syntax like this (note the `0b` prefix):

```
create table hash_values ( hash bit(64) );
insert into hash_values; 
  (0b0000000011111111000000001111111100000000111111110000000011111111)
```

For debugging purposes we need to display the bit values as strings of ones and zeros, but have only been able to do this with what feels like an ugly hack:

```
select conv(cast(hash as unsigned), 10, 2) hash from hash_values;
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| hash                                                             |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0000000011111111000000001111111100000000111111110000000011111111 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

This first uses `CAST()` to get an integer representation; then uses the `CONV()` method to covert it from base-10 back to base-2.  It seems to work, but I feel like we've overlooked a simple way to cast the bit value to a base-2 string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use [`BIN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_bin) function. You still have to `LPAD()` though, the higher order 0s are not displayed:

```
LPAD(BIN(hash), 64, '0')
```

Answer (score 2):

After a little more messing around I've found that I can skip the `CAST()` and just use `CONV()`, but it still seems as though there should be a better way:

```
select conv(hash, 2, 2) hash from `table`;
```

I also am using `LPAD()` to get the full 64-characters, which would be nice to avoid if possible (I'm hoping there's a function that infer the length from the `BIT(64)` definition).

```
select lpad(conv(hash, 2, 2), 64, 0) hash from `table`;
```